# TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path when using mongoose on browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

I am building a Nuxt.js application with backend and frontend integrated on the same project.

I created a /model folder with models to be used in backend and frontend.

To simplify, I have a model Address in file /model/Address.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Address= new Schema ({
  country:{type:String, default:''},
  zip:{type:String, default:''},
  addr1:{type:String, default:''},
  addr2:{type:String, default:''},
  phone:{type:String, default:''},
  fax:{type:String, default:''},
  
  center_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Center" },

});
export default (mongoose.models && mongoose.models['Address'])?mongoose.models['Address']: mongoose.model('Address', Address);
```

And also a AddressBook model contained in /model/AddressBook.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
import Address from './Address '

const AddressBook= new Schema ({
  name: { type: String, required: true,default:''},

  addresses: [Address.schema],

  center_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Center" },

});
export default (mongoose.models && mongoose.models['AddressBook'])?mongoose.models['AddressBook']: mongoose.model('AddressBook', AddressBook);
```

But I am getting this error on devtools console

> Uncaught TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `addresses`,
> got value "undefined"
> at Schema.add (browser.umd.js?8c0d:13972:1)
> at new Schema (browser.umd.js?8c0d:13517:1)
> at eval (Address.js?84b8:5:1)
> at ./model/Address.js (app.js:299:1)
> at **webpack_require** (runtime.js:854:30)
> at fn (runtime.js:151:20)
> at eval (index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/product/EditAddress.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2:87)
> at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/product/EditAddress.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
> (app.js:1139:1)
> at **webpack_require** (runtime.js:854:30)
> at fn (runtime.js:151:20)

Comment: What is sent in the network tab of the devtools?

Comment: What do you mean? I do not see anything weird in network tab

Comment: Did you achieved to send the proper payload so that your backend accepts it so?

Comment: The console error is being shown at devtools (client-side) when I am doing the import of `Address` model. `import Address from "~/model/Address";` It seems like mongoose is not working on browser side properly

Comment: Maybe try `Address.js` and also double check the path. Otherwise, Mongoose is indeed for the backend only, not sure why you would want to load it on client-side.

Comment: Tried with Address.js but still not working. Is there an alternative to have common models between backend and frontend when using mongoose for schema definition?

Comment: Mongoose should be used on the backend mainly. Send an HTTP call from your frontend to your backend with Axios or alike, and make the work there. Of course, you could use some tools to have a matching schema regarding your model but most people don't really need that kind of granularity.

Comment: Yes I am using HTTP calls with axios to communicate with backend. But I need the model reference to make a `new` object and send it to backend, that's why I am importing the models in frontend. Apparently mongoose works o.k. in this scenery when schema models are simple and have no references to other schemas, otherwise it breaks